# сортировка списка объектов по полю

Tags: python, сортировка, списки

В общем, у меня есть список объектов у котовый есть *поле-строка*. И есть список из таких же *полей-строк*, отсортированых специальным образом. Как отсортировать список объектов по списку *полей-строк*?

Пример 
Есть три объекта одного класса. Назовём их **a**,**b**, **c**, **d**. Они хранятся в списке **listOfObj**

```
listOfObj={a,b,c,d}
```

У этих объектов есть поле param:

```
a.param = g
b.param = k
c.param = k
d.param = f
```

Есть отсортирванный список полей

```
listOfParams= {f, g, k}
```

После сортировки списка объектов должно получиться

```
listOfObj={d, a, b, c}
```

Можно ли как то использовать метод sorted или же придётся использовать вложенные циклы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `sorted` можете попробовать как-то так:

`sorted(listOfObj, key=lambda elem: listOfParams.index[elem.param])`

Но может лучше этот специальный метод обернуть в функцию и прописать в `key` сортировки)

Comment: cпасибо большое!